# Bind collections into WPF radgridview(childgrid) using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, telerik-grid

I'm working on the functionality for Add,Edit,Delete in a `Gridview`. Now i have some 4 `Collections` which is binded into the `Gridview` and its child. All these collections are `ObservableCollection`. The binding was doing good, but when i try to add a new row in the main grid in which the child grid details are also given, the values of the collections are being shared in the new row.

//XAML

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grd1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1"  IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource NPISViewModel}}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNPIS, Mode=TwoWay}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="{Binding VisibleMode, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource NPISViewModel}}" GridLinesVisibility="Both"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding NPISList, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource NPISViewModel}}" GroupRenderMode="Flat" ShowGroupPanel="False" >                
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn />     
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Id" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <telerik:GridViewImageColumn Header="Sketch" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Sketch}" Width="80*" IsFilterable="False" />
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="RD #" DataMemberBinding="{Binding RDNumber}" Width="80*" />

                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>                
                    <telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grdChild1" ItemsSource="{Binding NPISItemsList, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource NPISViewModel}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNPISItem, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource NPISViewModel}}" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.98}" 
                                GridLinesVisibility="Both">
                                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Description" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="120*"/>
                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Unit #" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Number}" Width="80*" />
                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="WidthIn" DataMemberBinding="{Binding WidthInches}" Width="40*" />

                                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                            </telerik:RadGridView>
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grdChild2" ItemsSource="{Binding NPISCoversList, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource NPISViewModel}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNPISCover, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource NPISViewModel}}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.98}"  GridLinesVisibility="Both">
                                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="CoverName" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="120*" />
                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="ColorId" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ColorId, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="60*" />
                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="CleanCodeId" DataMemberBinding="{Binding CleaningInformationCode, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="60*" />


                            <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grdChild3" ItemsSource="{Binding NPISNotesList, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource NPISViewModel}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNPISNote, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource NPISViewModel}}"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" GridLinesVisibility="Both" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.98}" >
                                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Note" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Note, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="120*"/>

                                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                            </telerik:RadGridView>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
```

// ViewModel

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set npis list.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<NPISBO> NPISList
        {
            get { return m_NPISList; }
            set
            {
                if (m_NPISList != value)
                {
                    m_NPISList = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => NPISList);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set npis items list.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<NPISItemBO> NPISItemsList
        {
            get { return m_NpisItemsList; }
            set
            {
                if (m_NpisItemsList != value)
                {
                    m_NpisItemsList = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => NPISItemsList);
                }
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set npis covers list.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<NPISCoverBO> NPISCoversList
        {
            get { return m_NpisCoversList; }
            set
            {
                if (m_NpisCoversList != value)
                {
                    m_NpisCoversList = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => NPISCoversList);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set npis notes list.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<NPISNoteBO> NPISNotesList
        {
            get { return m_NpisNotesList; }
            set 
            {
                if (m_NpisNotesList != value)
                {
                    m_NpisNotesList = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => NPISNotesList);
                }
            }
        }


        NPISList = new ObservableCollection<NPISBO>(NPISModels.LoadNPIS(SelectedNPISId));
                NPISCoversList = new ObservableCollection<NPISCoverBO>(NPISCoverModels.LoadAllNPISCovers());
                NPISItemsList = new ObservableCollection<NPISItemBO>(NPISItemModels.LoadAllNPISItems());
                NPISNotesList = new ObservableCollection<NPISNoteBO>(NPISNoteModels.LoadAllNPISNotes());
```

Now i need only the new row to be created. Where i'm wrong?

**Note:** Telerik version **2013.1.403.45**

When i searched about this issue i got some points which may help.

1. `ObservableCollection` is lack of relationship(mapping) and so this issue occurs.
2. Instead of `RowDetails` in the grid use `ChildTableDefinition` which require `DataSet` but the `DataSet` shouldn't be used as per the application requirements. Either the `ObservableCollection` or `List<>` is good.

Comment: Please post your code for methods NPISModels.LoadNPIS(SelectedNPISId), NPISCoverModels.LoadAllNPISCovers(), etc.

Comment: Here is an example on how to add row to gridView. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834299/telerikradgrid-asp-add-new-record

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `SelectedNPISItem` setter does not populate child collections correctly.
But, to be honest, I would refactor the code so that NPISItem has collection properties. You can bind child grids to properties of items instead of global "have-it-all" collections. It would look like this:

```
public class NPISNote
{
  // properties
}

public class NPISItem
{
  public ObservableCollection<NPISNoteBO> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<NPISItemBO> NPISItemsList { get; set; }
}

<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource={Binding NPISItemsList, Source={StaticResource NPISViewModel}}>
 // columns
  <telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate> 
      <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource={Binding Notes}>
        // columns
      </telerik:RadGridView>
    </DataTemplate> 
  </telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Before adding a new row to `NPISItemsList` populate its' child collections with information relevant to the new data and binding will do the rest.